# How golang handle pointer in this JSON unmarshal example?

Tags: go

To deserialize JSON I found that we need to pass an output address to retrieve the result but for some reason I prefer to retrieve the result traditionally.

Here an example: https://play.golang.org/p/3hN1iLrDPGv

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    
)
type FruitBasket struct {
    Name    string
    Fruit   []string
    Id      int64  `json:"ref"`
    private string // An unexported field is not encoded.
    Created time.Time
}
type FruitBaskets []FruitBasket

func Deserialize(val interface{}) interface{} {
    serialBytes := `[{"Name":"Standard2","Fruit":["Apple","Banana","Orange"],"ref":999,"private":"Second-rate","Created":"2021-08-13T11:55:12.541568+07:00"}]`
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(serialBytes),&val)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
    }
    return val
}

func main() {
    out1 := Deserialize(&FruitBaskets{})
//  out2 := out1.(FruitBaskets) // I want this line
    out2 := out1.(*FruitBaskets)
    fmt.Println("Testing and got..",out2)
}
```

Comment: It is enough to pass `&FruitBaskets{}` to `Deserialize`, you don't need to also pass a pointer to `val`, if you do then you lose the type information. See: https://play.golang.org/p/B93NgBXE3QI

Comment: Note however that, instead of returning an unknown output value, it is much more useful to retain the input value. Then you do not have to do a type assertion. See:  https://play.golang.org/p/rMmFHSGlgdA

Comment: SO has A&Q format. Please do not put answers in question posts

Answer (score 2):

The stdlib JSON marshaller will always require a pointer to a struct to unmarshal into. If you attempt to pass in a value that is not a pointer, then a `json.InvalidUnmarshalError` will be returned.

It appears you are trying to write a method that will just return a value. In order to do this, you will need to create a `Deserialize()` function for each of your types, that return that specific type. For example:

```
func Deserialize(in []byte) (FruitBasket, error) {
    fb := &FruitBasket{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(in, &fb)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
        return FruitBasket{}, err
    }
    return *fb, nil
}
```

Once Generics have been introduced to Go, it will be possible to write a function that works for all types. But under the current constraints of the system it is not possible.

Comment: there is really no point into that Deserialize function https://play.golang.org/p/dCTy7yoCWnX

Comment: @mh-cbon, I know and agree. I would always prefer to just use JSON.Unmarshal, but that categorically would not have been answering the question. The user has asked specifically to have a function that will return the deserialised value.